# What does the trigger for It Ain't Easy Being Cheesy actually mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2018

### It Ain't Easy Being Cheesy

> Wear 6 hats, changing hats here in 6 days

- Does this mean wearing six hats across the network, but keeping one hat on for six days?
- Does it mean wearing six hats in six days on a particular site?
- Something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you click on the hat, you get the slightly longer and minimally less cryptic [description](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/it-aint-easy-being-cheesy):

> wear six different hats in total (anywhere), and change your hat on six different UTC days using the hat rack on this site

So there are two parts to earning this hat:

1. You have to put on (and thus have earned) six different hats. It doesn't matter if you wear the hat on a single site only or everywhere, and what StackExchange site profile you use (e.g. you can do it twice on your MSE profile, twice on your Puzzling profile, and twice on your Raspi profile).
2. On six different UTC days, you have to use the hat rack *on a specific site* to change your hat.

Part 1 isn't site-specific, so if you've earned the hat on one site, you don't have to do anything about 1) anymore.

Part 2 is the site-specific requirement that decides *where* you earn this hat, so if you want to earn this hat on multiple sites, this is what you have to do on each of them.

The philosphical description of this hat is

> wear lots of hats, but don't just go to your profile and wear six different hats over the course of two minutes to earn *It Ain't Easy*

However, since a hat is earned *on a particular site* there needs to be a site-specfic component to the requirement. That's what makes this hat's trigger a bit awkward to describe, especially when you need to make it short :(

Comment: So they don't have to be _consecutive_ days?

Comment: @hat No, not sure where that idea is coming from.

Comment: Just wondering...I thought I had changed hats here on six different days. It seems I haven't though. Thanks : )

Comment: @hat You've got 5 days here on MSE (12th, 14th, 15th, 18th, and 19th). One more :)

Answer (score 5):

It means wearing 6 hats in six days on a particular site. You should switch your hat on a specific site on six different days to earn that hat on that site.

Comment: Any minimum time that I need to wear that particular hat on a particular day?

Comment: Is there a limit to one change per day, though? Can I change my hat five times every day for six days?

Comment: @iLuvLogix it doesn't say so in the trigger description, so if you wear it on 23:59 UTC on one day and then switch to another hat on 00:00 UTC the next day, it should count as two.

Comment: @hat I think if you change multiple times in a single day, it will count as one. I don't think it will reset the counter. I didn't test it, though.

Comment: pseudo: `if (hats.used > 5 && hats.consecutivlyWorn > 5 days ) { get 
 this.cheesyHat }` ;)